# Load HTML file using MonoDroid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I  want to load an local html file as part of my Help Screen.  I have placed the file "test.html" in my Assets folder.

Here is my code:

```
WebView web_view;

web_view=FindViewbyId<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled=true;
web_view.LoadUrl("file://test.html");
```

I am getting a "Web page not available" error.

Thanks in advance.   TB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
web_view.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html);
```

Use this line instead of that

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, that fixed it.  I can deploy to my device (HTC-Inspire) using "debug" mode, but it doesn't work with "Release" mode.  I'll check elsewhere for a solution to that problem,

Answer (score 0):

```
web_view.LoadUrl("file:///test.html);
```

Use this line instead of that because use "file:///" not "file://" please change and after Run.

Comment: Sanjay, I'm still getting a Web Page Not Found error after I make your change.   I have the "first.html" file in the Assets folder and mark it's property as an Android Asset.